# In node, can I use a link to send data to an api via an express call?

Tags: html, node.js, forms, api, express

I have an html page. When the user clicks on a certain link, I need to send data to an api. I'm trying to do this via express using a form with a post method.

The link:

```
<form action="/bx/processed-manually" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="manProc" value="{{application_reference}}">
                <a>Decision manually processed</a>
            </form>
```

I've got the route set up:
**routes/routes.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.use('/bx/processed-manually', require('./manually-processed/processed-manually'));


module.exports = router;
```

The route:

**routes/manually-processed/processed-manually.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const { submitProcessedManually } = require('../../services/handler/manually-processed/processed-manually-handler');

router.post('/', submitProcessedManually);

module.exports = router;
```

And the route handler:
**services/handler/manually-processed/processed-manually-handler.js**

```
const callAPI = require('../../api');
const util = require('../../utils');

const submitProcessedManually = async (req, res) => {
    res.locals = req.session.data;
    let data = {
        "application_id": req.session.application_reference,
        "closure_reason": "offer_response_processed_manually"
    }
    const response = await callAPI.postClose(data);
    console.log(response);
    if (response[0] === 200 && response[1].status === 'SUCCESS') {
        console.log(`Application ${req.session.application_reference} successfully closed`);
        res.redirect('/bx/view-confirmation');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/bx/problem-with-service');
    }
};

module.exports = { submitProcessedManually };
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the anchor (`<a>`) element with a `<button>` (which is the correct element for submitting forms).

Comment: changing it to a button makes no difference, alas.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having arose from the fact that in HTML you cannot embed a form within a form. Who knew?